Installation and Running of Julia doesn't work on macOS
I want to install Julia on my Mac Pro, but every way I try it doesn't work and I'm out of options.
First Try:
install.packages("JuliaCall")
library(JuliaCall) 
julia <- julia_setup(installJulia = TRUE)

with this there is an error message every time, that the file is damaged and has to be deleted
Second Try:
library(JuliaCall)
install_julia()
Julia <- julia_setup()

sh: /Users/Tina/Library/Application Support/org.R-project.R/R/JuliaCall/julia/1.9.4/Julia-1.9.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia: No such file or directory
Error in julia_setup() : Julia is not found.
third try:
library(JuliaCall)
install_julia()
Julia <- julia_setup(JULIA_HOME = "/Users/Tina/.juliaup/bin")

The same "damaged file" message as in first try pops up
fourth try:
I installed Julia over their website with the help of the terminal
julia <- julia_setup(JULIA_HOME = "/Users/Tina/.juliaup/bin")

Error message: Julia version 1.11.1 at location /Users/Tina/.julia/juliaup/julia-1.11.1+0.aarch64.apple.darwin14/bin will be used.
Error in juliacall_initialize(.julia$dll_file, .julia$bin_dir, img_abs_path) :
jl_stdout_obj - dlsym(0x91f87b50, jl_stdout_obj): symbol not found
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

In general: To use julia with JuliaCall you need julia to be installed, JuliaCall is not Julia, it may just help you find/install it later. If install.packages("JuliaCall") fails, the subsequent steps cannot be started. Whats the error message after executing install.packages("JuliaCall")?

On top of that see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/53250#issuecomment-2429275901 . This means you have to wait for a fix of Error: jl_stdout_obj with Julia 1.11.

Thank you. There is no error message after install.packages("JuliaCall") .

Has this error in Julia been fixed? I'm trying to install Julia through JuliaCall but am getting the same error message: Error: jl_stdout_obj - The specified procedure could not be found.

Yes I got it fixed. There was an error in the installation process, it got installed to the wrong path. Once I fixed that, everything worked as it should
